# Need assistance understanding the std::find algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, find, std

I am using C++. I have used a snippet of code that works for me in my project using the std::find algorithm. It works, but I don't fully understand it. I was hoping someone could please help to explain it and rewrite this basic loop as a range based for loop. The code I used is:

```
if (std::find(closedList.begin(), closedList.end(), c.m_next) == closedList.end())
            {
                openList.push_back(c.m_next);
            }
```

My understanding is that the algorithm is searching for c.m_next between the beginning and end of the closedList (a list using < list > container). I tried to rewrite it as:

```
for (Node* node : closedList)
            {
                if (node == c.m_next)
                {
                    openList.push_back(node);
                }
            }
```

But my code does not work when re-written as a for each loop. To me these look the same. Have I understood the std::find algorithm correctly? If not, can someone help explain it to my by rewriting it as a for loop of some kind?

In the case of the code, c is an edge in a list of edges.
c.m_next is the destination node of the edge.
closedList is the list of nodes to be processed.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I particularly don't understand the purpose of == closedList.end() at the end of the loop, but I think that it means, if you haven't found the value you're looking for, c.m_next, and you reach the end, break out of the loop. Is that correct?

Comment: "code does not work" is not a useful problem statement. "Hello, Chuck's auto repair? My car doesn't work, what's wrong with it?"

Comment: We would need to see what our `Node` class looks like to be sure, but my guess is you're comparing a `Node*` to type `std::string`, for which the solution would be to compare `std::string`s with `std::string`s instead

Comment: If you're not sure how a function works, might I suggest googling it? The first result for "std::find" brings up cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find (from which: Return value: Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no such element is found.)

Comment: I haven't used std::string at all.

Comment: I did look at cppreference and it confused me. Too much information to wade through, sometimes a simple explanation is helpful.

Comment: My problem isn't "the code does not work".  If I wanted someone to fix my code, I would have given more code and information. I simply needed someone to explain the std::find to me. Please read the question next time.

Answer (score 1):

The original code adds 'node' to openList if it is NOT in closed list. Your code adds 'node' to the openList if it is in the closedList.

> If no elements match, the function returns last.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

You would want this to match behavior with a for each loop.

```
bool isInClosedList = false;
for (Node* node : closedList)
{
   if (node == c.m_next)
   {
      isInClosedList = true;
      break;
   }
}

if (!isInClosedList)
   openList.push_back(node);
```

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! To my eyes std::find does look like, "If it's in the closed list, do this", but you're saying it's the opposite of that. I find that a little confusing, but appreciate the explanation. Is it because of the last part, == closedListEnd()?

Comment: Yes exactly. If std::find finds the element you are looking for it returns an iterator to that element. If it does not find the element it returns an iterator representing the end of the list past the last valid value. Read the "Return value" section in the link in the answer and it may make more sense.